# No push notifcations on LG G PAD 8.3 with android 4.4.2

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notifications, tablet, notification-bar, push-notifications

I Just bought a new LG G PAD 8.3.
it says it currently has Android 4.4.2 version.

That's my first time with android, I have an iPhone so I'm used to see push notifications, both real time and all notifications that came through while the device was in sleep mode.

This doesn't happen with this Tablet though, even though notification alerts are set to ON, and on highest volume. I only get a few notifications, on  a random basis, and when I do get them, it's only if I'm actively using the device, and it plays a very vague light sound, it doesn't even play the voice I chose for notifications.

However, when I slide my finger from top to bottom to (Same as iphone), I do see the notifications listed in the notification bar, so I guess the problem isn't with the apps themselves.

Furthermore, I don't see a red number showing on the icon of the apps that indicates the number off missed notifications. I only see it on the facebook icon, but not on the icons of other apps.

Comment: The notification "badges" on app icons are not a feature of Android. Individual apps sometimes implement this by making a widget that looks like the app icon, and then updating that widget with a notification count. Facebook must be doing this, but not all apps do. I would actually say it's a fairly uncommon feature (in my experience).

Comment: absolutely no one?